# Using unison for sync, can't get backups working

Tags: backup, sync, unison

I'm using unison to sync a directory on my laptop with a directory on a network share. The sync is working, but I'd like unison to make backup copies, and I can't get that to work.

This is the command I'm currently using:

```
unison /home/robin/Sync/unison /media/nas/robin/unison -perms 0 -batch -auto -confirmbigdel=false -backuploc local -maxbackups 30 -prefer newer -fastcheck true -repeat 105
```

I had this working on Ubuntu Mate 18.04, but I've since upgraded to Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and now it doesn't work. I'm not sure exactly when the backups stopped working, so I'm not sure if the upgrade is relevant.

The unison preferences file just has a list of ignore paths.

There are no errors in the unison log, or when I run the command in a terminal (it's normally stared via cron).

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong, or ways to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Maybe try changing `backuploc` to `backuplocation`. Looking over [the manual](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#backups), `backuploc` seems to be the name for this option, BUT the manual more often refers to the `backuplocation` option, which isn't officially listed. *shrugs*

Comment: Also, what version of Unison are you now running on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @MikePierce Changing backuploc to backuplocation hasn't made any difference.  
  
The unison version is 2.48.4

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I added the option

```
-backup 'Name *'
```

and now it's creating backups.